# Azure data factory connecting to MongoDB via linked service connection timeout

Tags: mongodb, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I am trying to create a linked service in ADF to connect to a MongoDB and I am getting 30 second server timeouts.

I have the connection string and I can connect using Compass - my computer IP address is whitelisted - but I cannot connect through Azure linked service using their MongoDB connector with this connection string.

The Azure IP address ranges for my region have been added to the whitelist as well using the latest set published by Microsoft.  I am using an azurehostedingegrationruntime that is in the same Region the MongoDB is hosted in.

Problem is the MongoDB is hosted by a software house and I am not convinced they know what they are doing.  SSL is NOT enabled on the MongoDB and they are using the community edition v1.34.1, database is small < 0.75Gb.  The MongoDB instance is installed on a Linux box - I was looking at a selfhostedintegrationruntime but that requires a gateway installing on the server that in turn needs the use of a windows server.

If anybody has any experience of connecting to a MongoDB through Azure data factory your help would be appreciated.  The only option from the Azure end is the connection string and I know that is correct as I can connect using Compass with it, but it times out when trying to connect using Azure linked service so looks like it cannot see the MongoDB.

Connects ok with the given connection using Compass, just not using Azure even though the Azure IP addresses have been whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by the software house, so they do actually know what they are doing.

Don't need to use SelfHostedIntegrateionRuntime, the AzureHostedIntegrationRuntime works just fine.  Also no need to whitelist the Azure IPs - these are subject to revision anyway.

", but on the instance firewall, I have the option to allow the exact service and this should cover any future ip changes. For now, I have allowed access only for the "

Hope this makes sense.