I need to connect MongoDB which is hosted on Azure pull data via ADF
I have to pull data from MongoDB which is hosted on Azure (subscription 1) to ADF which is in Subscription 2.
i came across one article:
Azure data factory connecting to MongoDB via linked service connection timeout
i tried creating new Linked Service from my Dev environment for MongoDB atlas as my MongoDB version is 4.4.3
i used connection string as follows:
" mongodb://UserName:Password@10.xxx.xx.xx:2xxx7/? "

I am getting error as:

Failed to create a MongoDB client.
The connection string is not valid.

can someone please guide me on this please?

Did you follow any approach? Along with provide details about your mongo db?


You have provided the connection string format as below:
mongodb://UserName:Password@10.xxx.xx.xx:2xxx7/?

That is incorrect format, that maybe the reason to get above error. You should provide connection string in below format while creating to MongoDB Atlas linked service:
 mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<clustername>.<randomString>.<hostName>/<dbname>?<otherProperties>


Then you will be able to connect and test the linked service successfully. For more information you can refer to the MS document.

Hi, thank you for this clarification. I am expecting correct string from source team. However, do we need to open any firewall or something or it will just work with 'AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime'. as for below solution, it seems they have allowed IP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74729296/azure-data-factory-connecting-to-mongodb-via-linked-service-connection-timeout

check this MS document once.
